# MatLab - Controlling Markers in a Plot Using GUI Sliders

Tags: matlab, figure

I am trying to plot/control a `marker` within an `axes` object that I have created with 2 gui sliders that represent the `x` and `y` coordinates.  I want each slider to use its `value` properties to depict as to where the `marker` from the current `figure` will be.

Each slider has a range of `-4` to `4`.  I've tried getting the current `figure` handle by `fig = gcf` so I can try and control its properies via the `callback` functions from the sliders.  After looking at the properties for `fig`, I can't seem to find a property called `marker`.  At the moment I'm a little lost as to what to pass into my functions, etc.  Just to test if the `callback` functions are working I have `disp('test')` which is working fine.

Here is my code so far:

```
figure

% create x slider with handle
x_slider_h = uicontrol('style', 'Slider', 'Min', -4, 'Max', 4, 'Value', 0, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.08], 'callback', @changeX);

% create y slider with handle
y_slider_h = uicontrol('style', 'Slider', 'Min', -4, 'Max', 4, 'Value', 0, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.45 0.3 0.08 0.4], 'callback', @changeY);

% create axes with handle
axes_h = axes('Position', [0.09 0.32 0.4 0.5]);

% set axis equal to the sliders min and max
set(axes_h, 'YLim', [-4 4], 'XLim', [-4 4]);
```

I am also curious as to how you change the resolution of each slider, as I have tried to change a few properties from the `slider` handle like `SliderStep` thinking it would change the resolution.

Comment: Just to be clear: do you want to make a marker move around in your figure/axes, with its position defined by 2 sliders?

Comment: Hi - yes that is correct.  I want to be able to move slider 1 to move the marker on the X-axis and vice versa.

Comment: Alright I just posted an answer hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. 
I created a dummy function that you can copy/paste and try on your side. I created a listener object for both sliders, whose callback update the position of the marker after erasing the previous marker drawn. That should work for your particular application:

```
function UpdateMarker(~)
clc
clear

hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 400 400],'Units','normalized');

%// create axes with handle
handles.axes1 = axes('Position', [0.2 0.2 0.6 0.6],'XLimMode','manual','YLimMode','manual','XLim',[-4 4],'YLim',[-4 4]);

%// create x slider with handle
handles.x_slider = uicontrol('style', 'Slider','Min',-4,'Max',4,'Value', 0,'units','normalized','position', [0.2 0.08 0.6 0.08], 'callback', @(s,e) UpdateX);
handles.SliderxListener = addlistener(handles.x_slider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) XListenerCallBack);


% create x slider with handle
handles.y_slider = uicontrol('style', 'Slider', 'Min', -4, 'Max', 4, 'Value', 0, 'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.08 0.2 0.08 0.6], 'callback', @(s,e) UpdateY);
handles.SlideryListener = addlistener(handles.y_slider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) YListenerCallBack);

%// Some data to plot
handles.xdata = -4:4;
handles.ydata = sin(handles.xdata).*rand(1,numel(handles.xdata));

plot(handles.xdata,handles.ydata,'parent',handles.axes1)

%// set axis equal to the sliders min and max
set(handles.axes1, 'YLim', [-4 4], 'XLim', [-4 4],'XTick',-4:1:4,'YTick',-4:1:4);

guidata(hFig,handles);


    function XListenerCallBack

        handles = guidata(hFig); %// Get handles.

        axes(handles.axes1);
        set(handles.axes1, 'YLim', [-4 4], 'XLim', [-4 4]); %// Set axis limits

        hold on %// Important, otherwise it erases the current data plotted.

        %// Get position of both sliders
        xval = (get(handles.x_slider,'value'));
        yval = (get(handles.y_slider,'value'));

        %// Delete current marker
        delete(findobj(gca, 'type', 'patch'));

        %// Plot new marker.You can customize its properties as you want.
        scatter(handles.axes1,xval,yval,40,'r')

    end

    function YListenerCallBack

        handles = guidata(hFig);

        axes(handles.axes1);
        set(handles.axes1, 'YLim', [-4 4], 'XLim', [-4 4]);

        hold on

        xval = (get(handles.x_slider,'value'));
        yval = (get(handles.y_slider,'value'));

        delete(findobj(gca, 'type', 'patch'));
        scatter(handles.axes1,xval,yval,40,'r')

    end

    function UpdateY(~)

    end

    function UpdateX(~)

    end
end
```

Here is a screenshot of what the figure looks like:

[image]

Hope that helps! If something is unclear please ask!

Comment: Thanks for your answer - there is a lot of code, so I will have to go through it properly line by line as there are a few things you have written that I am not quite familiar with as yet.  Your image seems extremely close, but I actually don't need the marker (in red) to follow any curve or line.  Just to move about in the cartesian space via the sliders.  Also, what is the `~` argument if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Yes the marker can move around freely; I added a curve on the axes to make it look nicer :) The ~ is used to denote an absence of argument; that's not totally necessary but its a habit of mine to include it when functions don't have input arguments. If you have more questions please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Excellent - much appreciated!  Forgive me if I take time to answer the question as I need to get on with other work for today and tomorrow, so I will get back to this asap as it will be a pivotal part of my project.  I also think doing this purely code is better than using `GUIDE` as I think it generates an awful amount of code.  I'm hoping to have another graph next to it that converts the red marker to polar co-ordinates - but I must learn to crawl before walking or running extremely fast in this case!